Using VBA-JSON to retrieve the value of a key that is in an array
I'm trying to use VBA-JSON to parse a dump from Wiktionary. I gathered from the example here that if the key you are interested is in an array, you specify the index in parentheses starting from 1, and that if the key is in an object, you just refer to it the same way you normally would.
Below is my code followed by a sample entry. I am trying to retrieve the value of "sounds":[{"ipa" but getting a type mismatch:
Sub test_JC()
Dim dSht As Worksheet
Dim oSht As Worksheet
Dim json As Object
Set dSht = Worksheets("JSON")
Set oSht = Worksheets("JC")
For r = 1 To 100
 Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(dSht.Cells(r, 1))
 oSht.Cells(r, 1) = json("word")
 oSht.Cells(r, 2) = json("sounds")(1)("ipa") ' this is the line that causes the problem
 oSht.Cells(r, 3) = json("pos")
Next
End Sub

{
   "pos":"noun",
   "head_templates":[
      {
         "name":"th-noun",
         "args":{
            "1":"*",
            "2":"หลัง",
            "3":"แห่ง"
         },
         "expansion":"วัด • (wát) (classifier วัด or หลัง or แห่ง)"
      }
   ],
   "forms":[
      {
         "form":"wát",
         "tags":[
            "romanization"
         ]
      },
      {
         "form":"วัด",
         "tags":[
            "classifier"
         ]
      },
      {
         "form":"หลัง",
         "tags":[
            "classifier"
         ]
      },
      {
         "form":"แห่ง",
         "tags":[
            "classifier"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "descendants":[
      {
         "depth":1,
         "templates":[
            {
               "name":"desc",
               "args":{
                  "1":"en",
                  "2":"wat",
                  "bor":"1"
               },
               "expansion":"→ English: wat"
            }
         ],
         "text":"→ English: wat"
      },
      {
         "depth":1,
         "templates":[
            {
               "name":"desc",
               "args":{
                  "1":"ms",
                  "2":"wat",
                  "bor":"1"
               },
               "expansion":"→ Malay: wat"
            }
         ],
         "text":"→ Malay: wat"
      },
      {
         "depth":1,
         "templates":[
            {
               "name":"desc",
               "args":{
                  "1":"mfa",
                  "2":"واء",
                  "bor":"1"
               },
               "expansion":"→ Pattani Malay: واء"
            },
            {
               "name":"l",
               "args":{
                  "1":"mfa",
                  "2":"วะ"
               },
               "expansion":"วะ"
            }
         ],
         "text":"→ Pattani Malay: واء / วะ"
      },
      {
         "depth":1,
         "templates":[
            {
               "name":"desc",
               "args":{
                  "1":"urk",
                  "2":"วัยจ",
                  "tr":"wac",
                  "bor":"1"
               },
               "expansion":"→ Urak Lawoi': วัยจ (wac)"
            }
         ],
         "text":"→ Urak Lawoi': วัยจ (wac)"
      }
   ],
   "etymology_number":1,
   "etymology_text":"From Old Khmer វត្ត (vatta), វត (vata), វ័ត (vâta), វត្យ (vatya), វត្រ (vatra), វត្ថ (vattha), -វាត (°vāta, “Buddhist temple compound; monastery”). Possibly related to Old Khmer វត្ត៑ (“to encircle; to enclose > enceinte”). Cognate with Modern Khmer វត្ត (voat); Lao ວັດ (wat); Lü ᦞᧆ (vad); Shan ဝတ်ႉ (wâ̰t).",
   "etymology_templates":[
      {
         "name":"bor",
         "args":{
            "1":"th",
            "2":"okz",
            "3":"វត្ត",
            "tr":"vatta"
         },
         "expansion":"Old Khmer វត្ត (vatta)"
      },
      {
         "name":"m",
         "args":{
            "1":"xhm",
            "2":"វត",
            "tr":"vata"
         },
         "expansion":"វត (vata)"
      },
      {
         "name":"m",
         "args":{
            "1":"xhm",
            "2":"វ័ត",
            "tr":"vâta"
         },
         "expansion":"វ័ត (vâta)"
      },
      {
         "name":"m",
         "args":{
            "1":"xhm",
            "2":"វត្យ",
            "tr":"vatya"
         },
         "expansion":"វត្យ (vatya)"
      },
      {
         "name":"m",
         "args":{
            "1":"xhm",
            "2":"វត្រ",
            "tr":"vatra"
         },
         "expansion":"វត្រ (vatra)"
      },
      {
         "name":"m",
         "args":{
            "1":"xhm",
            "2":"វត្ថ",
            "tr":"vattha"
         },
         "expansion":"វត្ថ (vattha)"
      },
      {
         "name":"m",
         "args":{
            "1":"xhm",
            "2":"-វាត",
            "tr":"°vāta",
            "gloss":"Buddhist temple compound; monastery"
         },
         "expansion":"-វាត (°vāta, “Buddhist temple compound; monastery”)"
      },
      {
         "name":"cog",
         "args":{
            "1":"okz",
            "2":"វត្ត៑",
            "3":"",
            "4":"to encircle; to enclose > enceinte"
         },
         "expansion":"Old Khmer វត្ត៑ (“to encircle; to enclose > enceinte”)"
      },
      {
         "name":"cog",
         "args":{
            "1":"km",
            "2":"វត្ត",
            "tr":"voat"
         },
         "expansion":"Khmer វត្ត (voat)"
      },
      {
         "name":"cog",
         "args":{
            "1":"lo",
            "2":"ວັດ"
         },
         "expansion":"Lao ວັດ (wat)"
      },
      {
         "name":"cog",
         "args":{
            "1":"khb",
            "2":"ᦞᧆ"
         },
         "expansion":"Lü ᦞᧆ (vad)"
      },
      {
         "name":"cog",
         "args":{
            "1":"shn",
            "2":"ဝတ်ႉ"
         },
         "expansion":"Shan ဝတ်ႉ (wâ̰t)"
      }
   ],
   "word":"วัด",
   "lang":"Thai",
   "lang_code":"th",
   "sounds":[
      {
         "ipa":"/wat̚˦˥/",
         "tags":[
            "standard"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "synonyms":[
      {
         "word":"เทวสถาน",
         "_dis1":"0 0"
      },
      {
         "word":"เทวาลัย",
         "_dis1":"0 0"
      },
      {
         "word":"วัดวา",
         "_dis1":"0 0"
      },
      {
         "word":"วัดวาอาราม",
         "_dis1":"0 0"
      },
      {
         "roman":"wí-hǎan",
         "word":"วิหาร",
         "_dis1":"0 0"
      },
      {
         "word":"ศาสนสถาน",
         "_dis1":"0 0"
      },
      {
         "word":"สำนักสงฆ์",
         "_dis1":"0 0"
      },
      {
         "roman":"aa-raam",
         "word":"อาราม",
         "_dis1":"0 0"
      },
      {
         "word":"อาวาส",
         "_dis1":"0 0"
      }
   ],
   "derived":[
      {
         "roman":"dɔ̀ɔk-fáa-gàp-mǎa-wát",
         "word":"ดอกฟ้ากับหมาวัด",
         "_dis1":"0 0"
      },
      {
         "word":"วัดราษฎร์",
         "_dis1":"0 0"
      },
      {
         "word":"วัดวาอาราม",
         "_dis1":"0 0"
      },
      {
         "word":"วัดหลวง",
         "_dis1":"0 0"
      },
      {
         "roman":"mǎa-wát",
         "word":"หมาวัด",
         "_dis1":"0 0"
      },
      {
         "word":"วัดวา",
         "_dis1":"0 0 0 0"
      }
   ],
   "senses":[
      {
         "examples":[
            {
               "text":"ด้วยในศก ๑๒๗ บาดหลวงอีกอลอมเบต์วัดอาซัมชั่นกรุงเทพฯได้ออกเงินเกื้อกูลแก่อาไศรยสถานณะตำบลอ่างศิลา...\ndûai nai sòk · rɔ́ɔi yîi-sìp jèt · bàat-lǔuang ii-gɔɔ-lɔɔm-bee wát aa-sam-chân grung-têep dâai ɔ̀ɔk ngən gʉ̂ʉa-guun gɛ̀ɛ aa-sǎi-sà-tǎan ná dtam-bon àang-sì-laa ...",
               "ref":"1908-08-30, “แจ้งความกระทรวงมหาดไทย ลงวันที่ ๒๔ สิงหาคม รัตนโกสินทรศก ๑๒๗”, in ราชกิจจานุเบกษา, volume 25, retrieved 2019-10-31, page 633",
               "english":"Whereas, in the year 127, the priest I-ko-lom-be of Bangkok Assumption Cathedral had provided support money for the housing at Ang Sila Subdistrict...",
               "type":"example"
            }
         ],
         "links":[
            [
               "religion",
               "religion"
            ],
            [
               "religious",
               "religious"
            ],
            [
               "compound",
               "compound"
            ],
            [
               "place of worship",
               "place of worship"
            ],
            [
               "temple",
               "temple"
            ],
            [
               "sanctuary",
               "sanctuary"
            ],
            [
               "monastery",
               "monastery"
            ]
         ],
         "raw_glosses":[
            "(irrespective of the religion) religious compound or place of worship, as temple, sanctuary, monastery, etc."
         ],
         "qualifier":"irrespective of the religion",
         "glosses":[
            "religious compound or place of worship, as temple, sanctuary, monastery, etc."
         ],
         "id":"วัด-th-noun-K2DgVvC4",
         "categories":[
            {
               "name":"Religion",
               "kind":"topical",
               "parents":[
                  "Culture",
                  "Society",
                  "All topics",
                  "Fundamental"
               ],
               "source":"w",
               "orig":"th:Religion",
               "langcode":"th"
            },
            {
               "name":"Thai classifiers",
               "kind":"other",
               "parents":[
                  
               ],
               "source":"w+disamb",
               "_dis":"66 34"
            },
            {
               "name":"Thai nouns classified by วัด",
               "kind":"other",
               "parents":[
                  
               ],
               "source":"w+disamb",
               "_dis":"52 48"
            },
            {
               "name":"Thai nouns classified by หลัง",
               "kind":"other",
               "parents":[
                  
               ],
               "source":"w+disamb",
               "_dis":"52 48"
            },
            {
               "name":"Thai nouns classified by แห่ง",
               "kind":"other",
               "parents":[
                  
               ],
               "source":"w+disamb",
               "_dis":"52 48"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "examples":[
            {
               "text":"มาตรา ๑๖๒๓ ทรัพย์สินของพระภิกษุที่ได้มาในระหว่างเวลาที่อยู่ในสมณเพศนั้น เมื่อพระภิกษุนั้นถึงแก่มรณภาพ ให้ตกเป็นสมบัติของวัดที่เป็นภูมิลำเนาของพระภิกษุนั้น เว้นไว้แต่พระภิกษุนั้นจะได้จำหน่ายไปในระหว่างชีวิตหรือโดยพินัยกรรม์\nmâat-dtraa · nʉ̀ng-pan hòk-rɔ́ɔi yîi-sìp sǎam · sáp-sǐn kɔ̌ɔng prá pík-sù tîi dâai maa nai rá-wàang wee-laa tîi yùu nai sà-má-ná-pêet nán · mʉ̂ʉa prá pík-sù nán tʉ̌ng-gɛ̀ɛ-mɔɔ-rá-ná-pâap · hâi dtòk bpen sǒm-bàt kɔ̌ɔng wát tîi bpen puum-lam-nao kɔ̌ɔng prá pík-sù nán · wéen-wái-dtɛ̀ɛ prá pík-sù nán jà dâai jam-nàai bpai nai rá-wàang chii-wít rʉ̌ʉ dooi pí-nai-gan\nSection 1623 When a bhikṣu dies, the property of the bhikṣu which [the bhikṣu] had obtained during the time he was in the priesthood shall devolve upon the wat which is the domicile of that bhikṣu as the possession [of that wat], save where the bhikṣu has [already] disposed of [the property by means of a transaction] inter vivos or by [means of] a will.\nมาตรา ๑๖๒๔ ทรัพย์สินใดเป็นของบุคคลก่อนอุปสมบทเป็นพระภิกษุ ทรัพย์สินนั้นหาตกเป็นสมบัติของวัดไม่ และให้เป็นมฤดกตกทอดแก่ทายาทโดยธรรมของบุคคลนั้นหรือบุคคลนั้นจะจำหน่ายโดยประการใดตามกฎหมายก็ได้\nmâat-dtraa · nʉ̀ng-pan hòk-rɔ́ɔi yîi-sìp sìi · sáp-sǐn dai bpen kɔ̌ɔng bùk-kon gɔ̀ɔn ùp-bpà-sǒm-bòt bpen prá pík-sù · sáp-sǐn nán hǎa dtòk bpen sǒm-bàt kɔ̌ɔng wát mâi · lɛ́ hâi bpen má-rʉ́-dòk dtòk-tɔ̂ɔt gɛ̀ɛ taa-yâat-dooi-tam kɔ̌ɔng bùk-kon nán rʉ̌ʉ bùk-kon nán jà jam-nàai dooi bprà-gaan dai dtaam gòt-mǎai gɔ̂ɔ-dâai\nSection 1624 [When] any [item of] property has belonged to a person [since] before his ordination as a bhikṣu, such [item of] property does not devolve upon his wat as its possession and shall become the estate [which] passes on to the statutory heirs of that person or may be disposed of by that person in whatever manner according to the law.",
               "ref":"1935-06-07, “พระราชบัญญัติให้ใช้บทบัญญัติบรรพ ๖ แห่งประมวลกฎหมายแพ่งและพาณิชย์ พุทธศักราช ๒๔๗๗”, in ราชกิจจานุเบกษา, volume 52, retrieved 2019-10-31, page 544",
               "type":"example"
            },
            {
               "text":"มาตรา ๕ วัดกำหนดตามพระราชบัญญัตินี้เปน ๓ อย่าง คือ พระอารามหลวงอย่าง ๑ อารามราษฎร์อย่าง ๑ ที่สำนักสงฆ์อย่าง ๑...พระอารามหลวง คือ วัดที่พระเจ้าแผ่นดินทรงสร้าง...อารามราษฎร์นั้น คือ วัดซึ่งได้พระราชทานวิสุงคามสีมาแต่มิได้เข้าบาญชีนับว่าเปนวัดหลวง...ที่สำนักสงฆ์นั้น คือ วัดซึ่งยังไม่ได้รับพระราชทานที่วิสุงคามสีมา\nmâat-dtraa · hâa · wát gam-nòt dtaam prá-râat-chá-ban-yàt níi bpen · sǎam · yàang · kʉʉ · prá aa-raam-lǔuang yàang · nʉ̀ng · aa-raam-râat yàang · nʉ̀ng · tîi-sǎm-nák-sǒng yàang · nʉ̀ng ... prá aa-raam-lǔuang · kʉʉ · wát tîi prá jâao-pɛ̀n-din song sâang ... aa-raam-râat nán · kʉʉ · wát sʉ̂ng dâai prá-râat-chá-taan wí-sǔng-kaam-má-sǐi-maa dtɛ̀ɛ mí dâai kâo baan-chii náp wâa bpen wát lǔuang ... tîi-sǎm-nák-sǒng nán · kʉʉ · wát sʉ̂ng yang mâi dâai ráp prá-râat-chá-taan tîi wí-sǔng-kaam-má-sǐi-maa\nSection 5 Wat are divided by this Law into three types, namely, phra aram luang [being] one type, aram rat [being] one type, [and] thi samnak song [being] the other type... Phra aram luang are wat established by the monarch... Aram rat are wat which have been granted the wisungkhammasima but [whose names] have not yet been entered in the [public] register for recognition as public wat... Thi samnak song are wat which have not yet been granted the wisungkhammasima land.\nมาตรา ๘ วัดใดร้างสงฆ์ไม่อาไศรย ให้เจ้าพนักงาน...ปกครองรักษาวัดนั้น\nmâat-dtraa · bpɛ̀ɛt · wát dai ráang sǒng mâi aa-sǎi · hâi jâao-pá-nák-ngaan ... bpòk-krɔɔng rák-sǎa wát nán\nSection 8 [When] any wat is deserted [or] unoccupied by saṅgha, the [competent]...public officer shall take charge and care of that wat.",
               "ref":"1902-06-29, “พระราชบัญญัติลักษณปกครองคณะสงฆ์ (ร.ศ. ๑๒๑)”, in ราชกิจจานุเบกษา, volume 19, retrieved 2019-10-31, page 215",
               "type":"example"
            }
         ],
         "links":[
            [
               "law",
               "law#English"
            ],
            [
               "Buddhist",
               "Buddhist"
            ],
            [
               "compound",
               "compound"
            ],
            [
               "place of worship",
               "place of worship"
            ],
            [
               "temple",
               "temple"
            ],
            [
               "monastery",
               "monastery"
            ]
         ],
         "raw_glosses":[
            "(Thailand law) Buddhist compound; Buddhist place of worship; Buddhist temple; Buddhist monastery."
         ],
         "topics":[
            "law"
         ],
         "glosses":[
            "Buddhist compound; Buddhist place of worship; Buddhist temple; Buddhist monastery."
         ],
         "tags":[
            "Thailand"
         ],
         "id":"วัด-th-noun-cazUhIEa",
         "categories":[
            {
               "name":"Thai Thai",
               "kind":"other",
               "parents":[
                  
               ],
               "source":"w"
            },
            {
               "name":"Law",
               "kind":"topical",
               "parents":[
                  "Justice",
                  "Society",
                  "All topics",
                  "Fundamental"
               ],
               "source":"w",
               "orig":"th:Law",
               "langcode":"th"
            },
            {
               "name":"Thai nouns classified by วัด",
               "kind":"other",
               "parents":[
                  
               ],
               "source":"w+disamb",
               "_dis":"52 48"
            },
            {
               "name":"Thai nouns classified by หลัง",
               "kind":"other",
               "parents":[
                  
               ],
               "source":"w+disamb",
               "_dis":"52 48"
            },
            {
               "name":"Thai nouns classified by แห่ง",
               "kind":"other",
               "parents":[
                  
               ],
               "source":"w+disamb",
               "_dis":"52 48"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}


Do you have separate JSON documents in each cell of dSht? If that is the case, my guess is that in cell Ar you have a JSON that is not similar to the preceding JSON's with regard to ("sounds")(1)("ipa")
